# Email button for Custom Object List View

Tags: email, custom-object, email-template, list-view

Trying to create an action or button to show on a custom object list view to email selected records.

[image]

My goal is to send an email to selected records when I click on a Send an Email button. I get generic error above with no direction on what the problem is. It seems like this should be something that SF does OOTB easily, but I'm not seeing how to get there. If someone has a way around this error situation, great; otherwise, lmk if there is another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot add Send Email button on custom objects.  Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdkBuUAJ/add-send-list-email-button-on-custom-objects).

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_list_email_create.htm&type=5), You need to have a contact, lead, or campaign list view as a list email recipient.  However, you can check this example to create [Custom Send Email Button](https://www.biswajeetsamal.com/blog/custom-send-email-button-on-custom-objects/) on Custom Objects along with [Considerations for Sending List Email](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_list_email_considerations.htm&type=5).